# Is there a Scheme equivalent to SBCL's run-program?

Tags: scheme, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl, chicken-scheme

I can run `(run-program "/usr/ls" '())` in SBCL. Is there an equivalent in any Scheme implementation?

Answer (score 3):

GNU Guile also supports [`system`](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Processes.html) and other related functions (such as OS-level `fork` and `exec`).

Answer (score 2):

PLT/Racket supports [`system`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/subprocess.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/system..rkt%29._system%29%29), in different versions.

Comment: perfect! That works great. I wanted to to a program to learn from from started a program at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Chicken has [system](http://3e8.org/chickadee/library/system) as well. In Gauche it's called *sys-system*.